# Return the same values from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table and I want get the same rows that contain the same field value. Example:

**Table 1 structure:**

```
ID| CAPTION | TEAM
 0| Example | hi
```

**Table 2 structure:**

```
ID|  TEAM  | SELF
 0|  Eam2  | hi
```

So I want to return in one query all the rows that contains the `TEAM` and `SELF` field equal. In this case, I'm waiting this result:

```
0 - Example - hi
```

How I can achieve this? What's the statement in sql?

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

```
select *
from teams t1
where exists (select 1 from table players t2
                where t2.id = t1.id
                and t2.self = t1.players)
```

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table players t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.self' at line 3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can do it with simple select

```
select a.* from table1 a, table2 b where a.id = b.id and a.team=b.self
```

Comment: Why inlclude table2 rows in the select list? Will also return duplicate table1 rows if table2 contains duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh sure, this is redundant, changing

Comment: @Bender, glad that I helped you and thank you for acceptiong the anwer

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` to return a table1 row if table2 contains a matching row:

```
select t1.id, t1.caption, t1.team
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2
              where t2.id = t1.id
                and t2.self = t1.team)
```

Comment: you mean select t1 in the where?

Comment: You can select whatever you want in the EXISTS sub-select. I always chose 1. The important thing is if a row exists or not! (You don't use the value selected...)

Comment: Sorry, now I see my typo... Of course it's supposed to be "select 1 from table2" in the sub-select. Now corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this following one you may get your output.

```
select * 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.id = t2.id  and a.team = b.self;
```

Thanks.